# I have a question about using turtle graphic functions and looping methods on p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I have to create these two included images using the turtle function and the loop method on p5js and I am struggling I was given https://editor.p5js.org/dpapanik/sketches/_lbGWWH6N this code on p5js as a start please help, thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gmWB.png)

Answer (score 1):

So I've played around with some of the stuff for awhile, and I've created two functions. One that makes a *single* quadrant of the first problem, and one that creates a *single* wiggly line for the second problem. This is just a base for you to work of in this process. Here's each of the functions. Also, note that each of them takes in the turtle as a parameter:

```
function makeLineQuadrant(turtle) {
    // this currently makes the top left corner:
    let yVal = windowWidth * 0.5;
    let xVal = windowWidth * 0.5;

    for (let i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    // loop through the 12 lines in one quadrant
    turtle.face(0); // reset for the new round
    turtle.penUp();

    let startLeft = i * ((windowWidth * 0.5) / 12); // decide which component on the button we should start at
    let endTop = (12 - i) * ((windowWidth * 0.5) / 12); // how far down the y-axis should we go? You should write this out on paper to see how it works

    turtle.goto(startLeft, yVal);

    turtle.penDown();

    let deg = turtle.angleTo(xVal, endTop); // what direction do I need to turn?
    turtle.face(deg);

    let distance = turtle.distanceTo(xVal, endTop); // how far away is it?
    turtle.forward(distance);
  }
}
```

I tried to add a few comments throughout, but if there is any step that is confusing, please add a comment.

```
function makeSquiggle(turtle) {
  turtle.setColor(color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255)));
  let middleX = windowWidth * 0.5, middleY = windowHeight * 0.5;
  turtle.goto(windowWidth * 0.5, windowHeight * 0.5);

  // let's start moving in a random direction UNTIL our distance from the center is greater than some number X
  let X = 300; // arbitrary distance from center

  // some variables that can help us get some random movement for our turtle:
  let turtleXvel = random(-3, 3), turtleYvel = random(-3, 3);

  while (turtle.distanceTo(middleX, middleY) < X) {
    turtle.face(0);

    // calculate movement:
    let newXmove = turtle.x + turtleXvel, newYmove = turtle.y + turtleYvel;
    
    // direct our turtle:
    turtle.face(turtle.angleTo(newXmove, newYmove));

    let distance = turtle.distanceTo(newXmove, newYmove); // how far away is it?
    // move our turtle
    turtle.penDown();
    turtle.forward(distance);

    // change the velocity a little bit for a smooth curving:
    turtleXvel += random(-1, 1);
    turtleYvel += random(-1, 1);
  }
}
```

Note that I'm changing the velocities instead of the position directly. This is a classic Calculus / Physics problem where the derivative gives us a smaller range, so adjusting `turtleXvel` and `turtleYvel` change the position in much less drastic ways versus:

```
turtle.x += random(-1, 1);
turtle.y += random(-1, 1);
```

You should look at the difference as well to visualize this. Beyond this is working with these structural components to finish this up!